# rearrangements of ABCDE having exactly 1 letter in its original position.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

The question asks to find the no. of rearrangements of $ABCDE$ having exactly $1$ letter in its original position.

*(Rearrangement of a set means any arrangement of the set including its original ordering).*

Do we first have to fix an element (suppose $A$) and then have to find all the possible ways to arrange other $4$ elements in remaining $4$ positions?

Comment: Yes, that'll work. Then you can effectively ignore the correctly positioned letter, and just find the number of "derangements" of the remaining $4$ letters. It doesn't matter which exact letters they are, only that there are $4$ (distinct) letters. You can calculate the number of derangements of $4$ letters using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to choose an element, then to choose a permutation of the remaining elements *without fixed points* (a derangement). Since there are $9$ permutations without fixed points in $S_4$ ($3$ elements with the cycle structure of $(1\,2)(3\,4)$ and $6$ elements with the cycle structure of $(1\,2\,3\,4)$), the answer is $5\cdot 9=45$.

Answer (score 4):

**Alternative Method (Using Inclusion-Exclusion Principle):**

Fix any letter in its proper place, and the remaining $4$ have to be arranged such that none is in its proper place (so they become a derangement). Since the fixed letter is in its proper place, we can ignore it. Then the number of derangements of the other $4$ are:

> $4! -  \binom 4 1 3! + \binom 4 2 2! - \binom 4 3 1! + 0! = 9$

where there are:

> $4!$ total permutations of $4$ letters
>   $3!$ permutations with a (chosen) fixed letter, and $\binom 4 1$ ways to choose that letter
>   $2!$ permutations with two (chosen) fixed letters, and $\binom 4 2$ ways to choose them
>   $1!$ permutation with three fixed letters, and $\binom 4 3$ ways to choose them
>   $0!$ permutation with all letters fixed

There are $5$ possible letters (out of $ABCDE$) that can be fixed in its proper place, and $9$ derangements of the other $4$ letters, so the total number permutations with exactly one letter in its proper place is $5 \times 9 = \boxed{45}$.

*Note: There is no overlap between the permutations with $A$ in its proper place and all other letters deranged, and $B$ in its proper place and all other letters deranged, etc.*

One advantage of this method is that it can easily be generalized to $n$ letters.

> **Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion:**
>   Out of $N$ objects, the number of objects $N(\overline A_1 \overline A_2 \ldots \overline A_n)$ that *do not* have any of the $n$ properties $A_i$ ($i = 1, \ldots, n$), is
>   $$N(\overline A_1 \ldots \overline A_n) = N - N(A_1) - N(A_2) - \cdots - N(A_n) + N(A_1 A_2) + N(A_1 A_3) + \cdots + N(A_{n-1} A_n) - \cdots + (-1)^n N(A_1 A_2 \ldots A_n)$$
>   where $N(A_i)$ is the number of objects with property $A_i$, $N(A_i A_j)$ is the number of those with both properties $A_i$ and $A_j$, etc.

Comment: There exist a spelling error in $3!$ permutations with a (chosen) fixed letter, and $\binom 4 3$ ways to choose that letter. **$\binom 4 3$ should be $\binom 4 1$** (I can't edit since edits must be at least 6 characters)

Comment: @VincentBel Thanks! Mathematically they're equal, but of course, it should really be $\binom 4 1$. Appreciate the help.